# Setting pandas global default for skipna to False

Tags: python, pandas, sum, cumsum

For certain Pandas functions, such as sum(), cumsum() and cumprod(), there is an option for skipna which is set to True by default. This causes issues for me as errors might silently propagate so I always explicitly set skipna to False.

```
sum_df = df.sum(skipna=False)
```

Doing it every time one of these functions appear makes the code look a bit unwieldy. Is there a way I can change the default behaviour in Pandas?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not a satisfactory one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option is not an option (yet)

It seems there is nothing such an [option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options) to control this behaviour. It is hard coded:

```
import inspect
inspect.getfile(pd.DataFrame.sum)    # './pandas/core/generic.py'
inspect.getsource(pd.DataFrame.sum)

# @Substitution(outname=name, desc=desc, name1=name1, name2=name2,
#                  axis_descr=axis_descr, min_count=_min_count_stub,
#                  see_also=see_also, examples=examples)
# @Appender(_num_doc)
# def stat_func(self, axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None,
# [...]
```

It could be a good idea for pull request.

#### A simple solution

Probably not the best solution, it is a bit hackish but it does address your problem.

I am not saying that it is a good practice in general. It may have drawbacks that I have not addressed (you are welcome to list it in comment). Anyway this solution has the advantage to be *non intrusive*.

Additionally, although it is a quite simple technique and it is pure PSL, it may violate Principle Of Least Astonishment (see this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/305962/316969) for details).

#### MCVE

Lets build a wrapper that overrides existing default parameters or add extra parameters:

```
def set_default(func, **default):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(default)        # Update function kwargs w/ decorator defaults
        return func(*args, **kwargs)  # Call function w/ updated kwargs
    return inner                      # Return decorated function
```

Then, we can decorate any function. For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.sum = set_default(pd.DataFrame.sum, skipna=False)
```

Then, the `sum` method of `DataFrame` object has its `skipna` overridden to `False` each time we call it. Now the following code:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([1., 2., np.nan])
df.sum()
```

Returns:

```
0   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Instead of:

```
0    3.0
dtype: float64
```

#### Automation

We can apply this modification to many functions, at once:

```
for key in ['sum', 'mean', 'std']:
    setattr(pd.DataFrame, key, set_default(getattr(pd.DataFrame, key), skipna=False))
```

If we store those modifications into a python module (`.py` file) they will be applied at the import time without having the need to modify the Pandas code itself.

Answer (score 0):

It it perhaps not the best way, but I think you should **modify the pandas’ file**.

**1. Find the pandas’ file.**

If you installed pandas with pip, it should be in the Lib file, which is located in your python installation folder. If you do not know where python is installed, look it up on Google.

If you didn’t installed it with pip, look up on Google where are located packages installed with your software (anaconda or other)

**2. Find the DataFrame class and the method.**

The best way to do that, is to do CTRL+F or other letter to look for the method

**3. Change the default value.**

When you found the method(s), change `skipna=True` to `skipna=False`.

After you’ve done this, save the file and it should work !

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: Pandas `sum` method is not located where `DataFrame` object resides and it is substitution of `stat_func`. IMO, the best way to find where the code actually is without having to resort to google or find a keyword that is not present in a 10k lines file is `inspect` module which provides the required information in one single call. Changing, improving code is a good idea, sharing with other and test it is even better. Keeping track of modification is essential. Why not fork the [package](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) or make a pull request?