# How can we make pandas default handling of missing values warn of their presence rather than silently ignore them?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615856/does-pandas-current-treatment-of-missing-values-have-potential-to-cause-serious), pandas silently replaces `NaN` values with 0 when calculating sums, in contrast to explicit calculations as shown here:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

np.NaN + np.NaN                              # Result: nan
pd.DataFrame([np.NaN,np.NaN]).sum().item()   # Result: 0.0
```

[pandas' Descriptive Statistics](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html?highlight=skipna#descriptive-statistics) methods have a `skipna` argument. However, `skipna` is by default `True`, thereby masking the presence of missing values to casual users and novice programmers

This creates a risk that analyses will be ["...quietly, accidentally wrong since their Pandas operators haven't used the correct `skipna`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615856/does-pandas-current-treatment-of-missing-values-have-potential-to-cause-serious#comment130033644_73615856) .

In Python, is there a way for users to set `skipna=False` as the default option?

Comment: If you wanna set `skipna=False` globally, here is a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877832/setting-pandas-global-default-for-skipna-to-false).

Comment: Thanks Freda Xin! I hadn't use the right search terms to find this prior work. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward as in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html).

> skipna (bool, default True) - Exclude NA/null values when computing the result.

The `skipna` paramter in the `pd.DataFrame.sum()` method defaults to `True`. So, when you take column sum, it skips the nan values and returns sum = 0.

If you set it to `False` and you see the intended behavior. However, **there is no way of defaulting it to `False`. You have to set it to false via the parameter, unless you define your own wrapper around it.**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

np.NaN + np.NaN
pd.DataFrame([np.NaN,np.NaN]).sum(skipna=False)
```

```
0   NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

Here is a wrapper that can be defined to set your parameters to a custom value globally. This is code from this [excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877832/setting-pandas-global-default-for-skipna-to-false).

```
## Function from - 
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877832/setting-pandas-global-default-for-skipna-to-false

def set_default(func, **default):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(default)        # Update function kwargs w/ decorator defaults
        return func(*args, **kwargs)  # Call function w/ updated kwargs
    return inner                      # Return decorated function

pd.DataFrame.sum = set_default(pd.DataFrame.sum, skipna=False)
pd.DataFrame([np.NaN,np.NaN]).sum()
```

```
0   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay. That's great. I certainly did check the documentation you referenced, but I didn't find it at all straightforward to see what was needed. Your help is appreciated.